# How can I successfully reset my tablet in Factory Mode?

Tags: factory-reset, boot-loop

I was struggling into the rootview of my Teclast P78S tablet trying to change the `initlogo.rle` image. I was going to replace it with a image of my own, when I accidentally deleted the original `initlogo.rle`.

Although I've been warned by a message in terminal like

> initlogo.rle cannot be deleted. Read-only archive

It restarted my tablet and it is doing a **boot-loop** right now.

Solutions I've already tried:

- Holding Power + Vol (down or up) doesn't power on the phone in recovery mode at all..
- Theres a hardware "Reset" button, but when I press it, it get stucked at the boot-loop.
- I can't access ADB in order to replace the original initlogo.rle

What should I do?
Is my tablet **bricked**?

There should be a solution for such a poor mistake.

Comment: I'm guessing so. You can't access the bootloader or the recovery, right? 
On top of that, you can't access ADB. And the reset button doesn't work. 
High chance of bricking. The device is rooted and has a custom recovery, but is in a bootloop.

Comment: Which SoC does your device have ? (Qualcomm, Mediatek, etc.)

Comment: It's a Intel-based processor.

Comment: I have no idea about Intel, but for Mediatek devices, there is a tool called SP Flash tool, in which all partitions can be rewritten with a full firmware image. Do a Google search for a similar tool for Intel devices. Might show up some helpful results.

Comment: Heck. Those tools seem to require adb first..

Comment: Did you try to unplug the battery